# How to view internal code implementation of Python/Java in Pycharm/Eclipse respectively?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pycharm

New to programming and interested to understand the internal implementation of methods and classes of Java and Python Languages.

Is there any way to view the source code of these methods and or classes while using Eclipse and PyCharm ?
What are the shortcuts?

I understand the official documentation explains what the classes do but actually viewing the code really takes the veil off.

Comment: There are two completely separate questions here making it difficult to answer the question. For Java just using the JDK should let you read the runtime library source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the part of the Python standard library which is implemented in Python, you can use the standard PyCharm navigation shortcuts (Go to Definition, Go to Class) to jump to their source code.

A large part of the Python standard library is implemented in C, though. The C source code needs to be downloaded separately, and there is no support in PyCharm for navigating to the C source code.

For Java and Eclipse, the regular navigation shortcuts should work too.